# Noise function produce identical scale to initially random cubes

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to smoothly scale cubes with random initial scaling. The problem is that after some short time cubes scale almost identically, besides I'm using random noise function for scale. What's wrong with my code?

---

Preview is here https://twilight-sweatshirt.glitch.me/
Live snippet https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gakauv

As you can see cubes scaling becomes almost identical very fast.

---

Here's my code

```
    const random = require("canvas-sketch-util/random");
    const palettes = require("nice-color-palettes");

    random.setSeed(19);

    const palette = random.pick(palettes);

    // Ensure ThreeJS is in global scope for the 'examples/'
    global.THREE = require("three");

    // Include any additional ThreeJS examples below
    require("three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls");

    const canvasSketch = require("canvas-sketch");

    const settings = {
      // Make the loop animated
      animate: true,
      // duration: 5,
      fps: 30,
      playbackRate: "throttle",
      // Get a WebGL canvas rather than 2D
      context: "webgl",
      attributes: {
        antialias: true
      }
    };

    const sketch = ({ context }) => {
      //#region Scene setup
      // Create a renderer
      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas: context.canvas
      });

      renderer.setClearColor("aquamarine", 1);

      const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera();
      const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, context.canvas);
      const scene = new THREE.Scene();

      scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040));

      const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 5, 15);
      light.position.set(-1, 2, 4).multiplyScalar(1.5);
      scene.add(light);

      const light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.5, 15);
      light2.position.set(3, 0, 2).multiplyScalar(1.5);
      scene.add(light2);

      const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);

      const getNoise = (x, time) => {
        return random.noise2D(x, time, 0.5) * 0.5 + 0.5;
      };

      for (let index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
          geometry,
          new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
            color: random.pick(palette),
            flatShading: true,
            roughness: 0.75
          })
        );
        mesh.name = `mesh-${index}`;
        mesh.position.set(
          random.range(-1, 1),
          random.range(-1, 1),
          random.range(-1, 1)
        );
        mesh.scale.set(
          random.range(0.04, 0.5),
          random.range(0.04, 0.5),
          random.range(0.04, 0.5)
        );
        scene.add(mesh);
      }
      //#endregion

      // draw each frame
      return {
        // Handle resize events here
        resize({ pixelRatio, viewportWidth, viewportHeight }) {
          renderer.setPixelRatio(pixelRatio);
          renderer.setSize(viewportWidth, viewportHeight, false);

          const aspect = viewportWidth / viewportHeight;

          // Ortho zoom
          const zoom = 1.5;

          // Bounds
          camera.left = -zoom * aspect;
          camera.right = zoom * aspect;
          camera.top = zoom;
          camera.bottom = -zoom;

          // Near/Far
          camera.near = -100;
          camera.far = 100;

          // Set position & look at world center
          camera.position.set(zoom, zoom, zoom);
          camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3());

          // Update the camera
          camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        },
        // Update & render your scene here
        render({ time, playhead }) {
          scene.children.forEach(obj => {
            if (obj.isMesh !== true) {
              return;
            }
            // console.log(`${obj.name}: `,getNoise(obj.scale.z, time));
            // console.log(scene);
            obj.scale.set(
              // obj.scale.x,
              // obj.scale.y,
              // obj.scale.z,
              getNoise(obj.scale.x, time),
              getNoise(obj.scale.y, time),
              getNoise(obj.scale.z, time)
            );
          });

          controls.update();
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
        },
        // Dispose of events & renderer for cleaner hot-reloading
        unload() {
          controls.dispose();
          renderer.dispose();
        }
      };
    };

    canvasSketch(sketch, settings);
```

Comment: I see the noise in your working example. Maybe the noise is so little that you can't appreciate it? It can be a screen matter

Comment: I can surely see the noise results cuz the cubes are scaling. But they scaling the same way and become almost identical. Here's how they look like initially [pic](https://uig5bq.dm.files.1drv.com/y4m6ohj2Jvel6bK2a891z-ukHxJpmMUgXXwN-rAeNJAgSOVKC37_P5Ya-KXKNd_KeVrMo91gyTova6wmXMijnnzArLT3AO5hZmZYJ3FjTckgLtNZ2_jKcsihHNbsFevZ1r6vRJC9YGYs7chtgaZrF4mxV-a0K7ZI7LDyHRILhpzewEDq_W_v1u06zQIWo5Rg5SlWQlirvq2Pd5R1j3NwL0JGA?width=609&height=702&cropmode=none)

Answer (score 1):

For the maximum calculation, the noise difference was much so it was flickering the box.

Try Setting these parameters

```
return random.noise2D(x, time, 0.8) * 0.2 + 0.5;
OR
return random.noise2D(x, time, 0.7) * 0.3 + 0.5;
OR
return random.noise2D(x, time, 0.6) * 0.4 + 0.5;
```

Choose as per your frequency.

See, if this is what your were looking for https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hhurr3?file=index.js

Comment: It doesn't work out. The only change is time value becomes a bit random and noise isn't smooth anymore. Nonetheless, noise function should provide different values from different input, but after the short time values become almost identical.

Comment: can you provide the working environment somewhere at stackbliz?

Comment: Sure mate. Here it's live https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gakauv

Comment: Added the code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mxduwu?file=index.js

Comment: correct me, if I'm getting your problem wrong, Are you finding the issue of sudden flickering of box OR they are scaling similar and they should scale separately. i.e. with both should show the different size at same time?

Comment: Well, it's actually both but the main issue is that they should scale separately. Flickering is now fixed by the way. Thanks.

Comment: The actual problem is with the `time` variable and at same time it is setting both cube and axis with same value, I have added a new library tweenMax hope that helps you https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hhurr3?file=index.js